# Does xtk.js supports IE-8,9,10?

Tags: internet-explorer, xtk

I have started learning xtk.js. I am playing with sample available on
https://github.com/xtk/X  .When i run those sample in firefox, chrome it works fine but when i run same samples in IE-8,9,10 it doesn't show anything?
Does anybody knows why it is not working in IE? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. And there are no plans to support IE<11 either. Versions of IE<11 do NOT support WebGL, so it's all moot really. By definition you need a WebGL compliant browser, and IE only provided WebGL support from version 11.

Answer (score 0):

Although xtk.js was a javascript item, if the browsers did not support with HTML5 or CSS3, of cause it can not work.

IE 8 - 10 introduction: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer